# How to get a specific date from an object / collection with eloquent methods like 'where'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I want to implement a chart in my website with chartjs. I am trying that with laravel and I made a function with an Object (Provider) with relations (products, results) and I want to filter it. I just want to have the results of the **actual month** / **actual year**. So I tried many things and I can't provide a simple, clean code solution.

I tried following things:

1. $providerResults->results->where('created_at','2019-01-28 00:00:00') *// this is working but I just want to filter with '2019' or '1' for january*
2. $providerResults->results->where('created_at', 'LIKE','%2019%') *// not working*
3. $providerResults->results->where('created_at', 'LIKE','%2019%')->get() *// not working*
4. $providerResults->results->whereIn('created_at', 2019); *// not working*

Maybe using filter()?

```
private function getResultsForChart($objProvider) {

    $providerResults = $objProvider
        ->where('id', AUTH::user()->provider_id)
        ->with('products')
        ->with('results')
        #->whereYear('created_at', 2019)
        #->whereMonth('created_at', 1)
        ->first()
    ;

    $providerResultsForChart = $providerResults->results->whereIn('created_at', 2019);

    dd($providerResultsForChart);

    return $providerResultsForChart;

}
```

My expected result would be my collection just with the actual month/ actual year instead of everything.

I hope somebody can help me with a hint or a direction which I can use to solve my problem.

**Thank you** very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried it as below:
where('YEAR(created_at)','2019') OR where('MONTH(created_at)','1')

Comment: @Pragna Hey there, unfortunately your hint is not working. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it using the eager loading with conditions like this :

```
$providerResults = $objProvider
        ->where('id', AUTH::user()->provider_id)
        ->with('products')
        ->with(['results' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereYear('created_at', 2019)
                  ->whereMonth('created_at', 1);
        }])
        ->first();
```

Comment: Hey there, I tried it and it's working great! Really good idea with the eager loading. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$year = 2019;    
$providerResults = $objProvider
            ->where('id', AUTH::user()->provider_id)
            ->with(['products', 'results' => function ($q) use ($year) {$q->where('created_at', 'LIKE', $year.'%');}])
            ->first();
```

Try like this. 
`$providerResults->results` should return you just results from 2019;

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the eager loading is working great!